# Github Actions - Permission denied error during workflow execution

Tags: linux, github, github-actions

I am getting the following error during the actions workflow execution:

```
/app/actions-runner/_work/_temp/13f3b0d9-2780-4fb3-8696-5723c161741b.sh: line 2: /opt/my_space/env_promotion.txt: Permission denied
```

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I am using a self hosted runner (Linux env) hosted in AWS EC2.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks